# jar-file в persistnce.xml при использовании maven

Tags: maven, jpa

Как указать jar-файл в persistence.xml, в котором лежат entity, созданные во внешнем проекте, в случае использования сборщика maven.

Используется Netbeans. В persistence.xml задействован  EclipseLink(JPA 2.1).

Answer (score 0):

Добавить этот jar как зависимость в **pom.xml**